# Set dataset defaultvalue dynamically

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, dataset

On my sql-server i have a stored procedure that gives me the dataset of the logged in windowsuser: ID,Name, WindowsUserName, Birthday, just one dataset. I wanna set the WindowsUserName as defaultvalue in my vb.net dataset. I tried to find a hint weather it is possible to write a command into the defaultvalue field but couldnt find anything.
Reason: I wanna have that name filled in my datagridview when i create a new row. 
Problem: I cannot set a defaultvalue manually since the value changes for each user. 
How do i get that WindowsUserName as a default value in my dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataColumn.DefaultValue is an object type. You cannot add commands to it like you would a SQL column's default value and expect them to be executed. For example, if you set the default column's value to  DateTime.Now() the date/time from the point that line of code was executed would be used for all default values in the data table. DateTime.Now() would NOT be re-evaluated each time a row was created and every row in the table would have the same date/time assigned.

You will have to assign the desired Windows Username for each row in your table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue.aspx